# Golang issue in vs code while accessing private repo

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a Golang project and the version I am using is 1.13. And my module is hosted in my private repo. And my repo starts with:

```
module <Private-Repo>-service

go 1.13
```

And there are some Repos that are from Github and go packages. I am using Golang's vs code package

> Go Team at Google

I have my env like:

```
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOPATH="/home/{User}/go"
GOPRIVATE=<Private-Repo-URL>
```

And my folder where I am copying my Repo is inside  /home/{User}/go/src/

But I am unable to fix the issue and it is saying:

```
could not import github.com/golang/mock/gomock (cannot find package "github.com/golang/mock/gomock" in any of 
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/mock/gomock (from $GOROOT)
    /home/{User}/go/src/github.com/golang/mock/gomock (from $GOPATH))compilerBrokenImport
```

So I need to fix this issue in the visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

Try first if the issue persists:

- in command-line (go get github.com/golang/mock/gomock, in the root folder of your project, where `go.mod`/`go.sum` are)
- after upgrading, if possible, to go 1.17.

Once a go build is working in command-line, you can switch back to VSCode, and confirm it is also fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your code directly inside your `$GOPATH`, try to store it inside another directory namely `github.com/{github-username}/`.

From:

```
/home/{User}/go/src/
```

To:

```
/home/{User}/go/src/github.com/{github-username}/
```